# add a code for linux kernel that runs on boot

Tags: c, linux, memory, kernel, allocation

I want to add some code to my Linux 3.10 kernel that will run and use the `alloc_bootmem(unsigned long size)` function to allocate memory. 
I understood that `alloc_bootmem(unsigned long size)` runs only in the boot stage, so I need my code to run in booting.

The problem is that I don't know how to make my function be called when the computer is booting.

I'm searching for a main function in Linux kernel that runs in the boot stage and calls all different of functions that also need to work in the boot stage. I want to add a line to this function that calls my code.

Can anyone show me this kind of function? 
Is this the best way to add code that uses `alloc_bootmem` in the booting stage to the Linux kernel?

Thanks For Help!

Comment: Why do you want to do that in kernel land? Can't you make some userland process help you?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, I can't. It is a part of more complex project and I have to allocate a big chunk of memory...

Answer (score 0):

The `start_kernel` function in `init/main.c` is kernel entry point. There some functions call `alloc_bootmem` (like `setup_command_line`).